Cyrillic letter 'т' in hash or list literals breaks the powershell (5.1) script
Execution of powershell-5.1 script files that contains hash or list literals with cyrillic letter 'т' failed with errors.
Similar question was there:
Powershell choking on cyrillic т
For example, this script (UTF-8 encoding)
$dict = @{'т' = '123'}
# or $list = 'z', 'т'
echo 'Hello world'

produces this error:
At C:\xxx\test.ps1:1 char:19
+ $dict = @{'С‚' = '123'}
+                   ~
Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.
At C:\xxx\test.ps1:2 char:18
+ echo 'Hello world'
+                  ~
The string is missing the terminator: '.
At C:\xxx\test.ps1:1 char:19
+ $dict = @{'С‚' = '123'}
+                   ~
The hash literal was incomplete.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEqualsInHashLiteral


Powershell info:
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.6640
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.6640
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000


use double-quotes, your character is being interpreted as a single-quote that requires escaping. see: https://i.imgur.com/Me0yLZ7.png

Since the problem occurs with string literals in your source code, the likeliest explanation is that your script file is misinterpreted by the Windows PowerShell engine, which happens if the script is saved as UTF-8 without a BOM (this is no longer a problem in PowerShell (Core) 7). Try saving your script as UTF-8 with BOM.
See the linked duplicate for details.

@mklement0 this issue isn't related to encoding you can clearly see a parsing error due to unescaped quote in the error message. OP already stated the file is saved in UTF8

@SantiagoSquarzon, the parsing error is the result of the misinterpretation of the script due to the encoding mismatch (BOM-less UTF-8 being misinterpreted as ANSI-encoded by Windows PowerShell), note that the original source code line is $dict = @{'т' = '123'}

@mklement0 ah i see, nevermind, i misinterpreted the question
